# List Adapter Diff Util not updating the List Item in Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-diffutils

List Adapter diffutil not updating the list item in recyclerview.

It works when I add or remove a item from the list. But not updating the any particular value like `isSelected : Boolean = false` in object class

How to update the recyclerview view when one of the object class in list is changed like value Boolean changes in one object class

Thankyou

Adapter Class Below

```
class CategoryMainAdapter(
    var itemClick : CategoryItemClick,
    var screenWidth : Int = 0
) : ListAdapter<CategoryModel, CategoryMainAdapter.CategoryMainViewHolder>(CategoryMainDiffUtils()) {

    inner class CategoryMainViewHolder(val binding : CategorySingleListLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoryMainViewHolder {
        val binding = CategorySingleListLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from
            (parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return CategoryMainViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoryMainViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val model = getItem(position)
        holder.apply {
            binding.apply {
                mainLinearLayout.layoutParams.apply {
                    width = ((screenWidth*22.5).toInt())/100
                    height = (((screenWidth*22.5)/100)*1.2).toInt()
                }
                categoryName.text = model.name
                backgroundColor.setBackgroundColor(model.colorCode)
                categoryImage.load(getImageCorrectImage(model.image, model.secondaryImage)) {
                    error(R.drawable.ic_food_place_holder)
                }

                if (model.isSelected) {
                    categoryName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(categoryName.context, R.color.main_blue))
                    selectedView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_blue_curved_bg)
                    categoryImage.apply {
                        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.category_zoom_in_anim)
                        setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                    }
                } else {
                    categoryName.setTextColor(setColorByAttrProgrammatically(categoryName.context, R.attr.colorOnSecondary))
                    selectedView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
                    categoryImage.apply {
                        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.category_zoom_out_anim)
                        setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1)
                    }
                }
            }
            itemView.apply {
                setOnClickListener {
                    itemClick.onCategoryClick(model)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    class CategoryMainDiffUtils : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CategoryModel>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CategoryModel, newItem: CategoryModel): Boolean {
            return oldItem.isSelected == newItem.isSelected
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CategoryModel, newItem: CategoryModel): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    override fun submitList(list: MutableList<CategoryModel>?) {
        super.submitList(list?.let { ArrayList(it) })
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your adapter class with question . Add minimal code only if its too big .

Comment: Hi ADM, I added my adapter code in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, the implementation of `areContentsTheSame` and `areItemsTheSame` probably needs to be switched. `areContentsTheSame` is the one that checks if things in your items are different. `areItemsTheSame` is about whether it is the same item. If the items have an id you might want to compare them instead of the item themselves. But that alone probably won't fix your issue.

The thing is, ListAdapter works best if the list has items that are immutable. Ideally you want to submit a new list every time you call `submitList`. Because if you change a property like `isSelected` in the existing lisk and simply call submitList with that same list nothing will happen.

So what you want to do is instead of changing the `isSelected` property you need to create a copy of the list and in that copy alone you change the `isSelected` and pass the copy to `submitList`.

This can be tedious to make. An alternative ugly workaround that might work is to add a second property maybe called `oldIsSelected` and only change that one in the DiffUtil itself, like this

```
    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CategoryModel, newItem: CategoryModel): Boolean {
        val result = oldItem.oldIsSelected == newItem.isSelected
        newItem.oldIsSelected = newItem.isSelected
        return result
    }
```

Comment: Your both answer doesn't work for me. Below is my copy the list method ```ArrayList(categoryList.map { it.copy() }).toMutableList().let { list ->
                    list.forEach { resultCategoryModel ->
                        resultCategoryModel.isSelected = false
                        if (resultCategoryModel.id == categoryModel.id) {
                            resultCategoryModel.isSelected = true
                        }
                    }
                    submitList(categoryList)
                } ```

Comment: This is the tedious method  ```val result = oldItem.isSelected == newItem.isSelected
            newItem.isSelected = newItem.isSelected
            return result ``` Both of the method not work for me....  @Ivo Becker

Answer (score 0):

Try update your DiffUtil to something like:

```
class CategoryMainDiffUtils : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CategoryModel>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CategoryModel, newItem: CategoryModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id // or compare something unique
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CategoryModel, newItem: CategoryModel): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem // or if data class is large, compare only things that might change, also please note that only data class on kotlin has auto generated equals() method
    }

}
```